# IntentService to save to Database or AsyncTask?

Tags: android-studio, android-asynctask, intentservice, android-intentservice

Currently my app works like this:

`MainActivity` calls `WebService` to download potentially thousands of Database Records.

Next, `WebService` sends a callback to `MainActivity` telling it that it is done downloading, along with the data.

Then, `MainActivity` calls `DBHelper` which asynchronously saves all data, and then `onPostExecute()` uses a callback to tell `MainActivity` it is done.

Finally upon getting the callback from `DBHelper`, `MainActivity` displays all the data that was just donwloaded in a table form.

In short its like: `MainActivity->WebService->MainActivity->DBHelper->MainActivity`

The problem is, `MainActivity` is rather cluttered with all of these callbacks implemented, and its hard to follow. I would like to separate the downloading/saving into a separate IntentService class, and since IntentService runs on it's own thread, I would get rid of the Async Tasks in `DBHelper` and instead just tell the IntentService that saving is done in `DBHelper` at the bottom of the `DBHelper.save()` function. I am worried that somehow IntentService will get told that saving is done, when really the records are still being saved.

Is the IntentService  method I want to do reasonable or the correct way to go here? Would it work without any weird side effects like described above?

Comment: In your intentService proposal, will DBHelper.save() start an asyncTask or a thread? Or will it return ONLY after the saving is done?

Comment: It will return only after the saving is done. I found out that this causes skipped frames and now I have put it in an asyncTask.